# Using the Jenkins pipeline docker plugin, how to pull an image and push a new tag to it?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an image already in my private repo. I need to pull that image, create a tag and push it to the registry.

**What's the bes way to do this using the Jenkins WithRegistry ?**

Here's my actual code:

```
        stage("Applying to docker repo") {
        steps {
            script {
              def imageNameLookup = configs.dockerRegistry.repo + "/"+repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag
              echo 'looking up '+ imageNameLookup
              docker.withRegistry('https://' + configs.dockerRegistry.url, configs.dockerRegistry.credentialsId) {

                try {
                  image = docker.image(repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag).pull()
                  image.tag("${deliveryTag}")
                  image.push()
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  echo ' catch 2 '+ e.getMessage()
                }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

When running the image.tag(), i get the following error :

> bfc9288fe86d: Pull complete
>   Digest: sha256:ee9b01eb62f2f21dcb3bf4af285702c8991d1789e659515fdfa2da2619f1d8b9
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for repodocker-xxx.xxx.xx/my-api:1.19.0
>   [Pipeline] echo
>    catch 2 Cannot invoke method tag() on null object

**EDIT:**
I was able to pull the image but when I try to create the tag, I get a new error : **No such image :latest**

I don't need to set the tag latest because I'm tagging another version.

> ```
>               docker.withRegistry('https://' + configs.dockerRegistry.url, configs.dockerRegistry.credentialsId) {
> ```

```
                try {
                  docker.image(repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag).pull()
                  sh "docker tag ${repo.toLowerCase()} ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${deliveryTag}"
                  sh ""
                 )
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  echo ' catch 2 '+ e.getMessage()
                }
```

and my new log :

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull repodocker-xxxx.xxx.xx/myapi-api:1.19.0
1.19.0: Pulling from myapi-api
Digest: sha256:ee9b01eb62f2f21dcb3bf4af285702c8991d1789e659515fdfa2da2619f1d8b9
Status: Image is up to date for repodocker-xxxx.xxx.xx/myapi-api:1.19.0
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag myapi-api grdocker-xxxx.xx.xx:443/xx.xxx.xxx/myapi-api:testTag20
Error response from daemon: No such image: myapi-api:latest
[Pipeline] echo
 catch 2 script returned exit code 1
```

**EDIT2**
was able to do it by doing it this way :

```
        stage("Applying to docker repo") {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry('https://' + configs.dockerRegistry.url, configs.dockerRegistry.credentialsId) {
                  docker.image(repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag).pull()
                  sh "docker tag ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${params.versionToTag} ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${deliveryTag}"
                  sh "docker push ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${deliveryTag}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**FINAL EDIT**
Here's the final solution in Jenkins and the docker plugin which was not able to do everything.

```
        stage("Applying to docker repo") {
        steps {
            script {
                  docker.withRegistry('https://' + configs.dockerRegistry.url, configs.dockerRegistry.credentialsId) {
                  docker.image(repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag).pull()
                  sh "docker tag ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${params.versionToTag} ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${deliveryTag}"
                  sh "docker push ${configs.dockerRegistry.url}/${repo.toLowerCase()}:${deliveryTag}"
                  docker.image(repo.toLowerCase()+":${deliveryTag}").pull()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have installed docker-engine and your server should  have access the registry:

- console `docker login ip_registry:5000`
- stage:

```
stage('registry') {
            steps {
                sh "docker tag ${imageName} ${registryServer}/${imageName}:latest"
                sh "docker push ${registryServer}/${imageName}:latest"
            }
        }
```

Comment: change **latest** for your version ${version}

Comment: I will accept your answer snce it is the closest to what I have done. I didn't want to use sh but the plugin which doesn't seem to provide that.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below to push image with new tag:

```
try {
    image = docker.image(imageNameLookup+":"+params.versionToTag)
    image.pull()
    image.push("${deliveryTag}")
} catch (Exception e) {
    echo ' catch 2 '+ e.getMessage()
}
```

Comment: I still have that error : Cannot invoke method push() on null object

Comment: What is `repo.toLowerCase()+":"+params.versionToTag`? Are you sure that image exists to pull exists? Try pull with `imageNameLookup`